# Seleccionar el primer valor de un decimal

Tags: javascript

Buenas,

Hay alguna manera de seleccionar el primer valor de un decimal, intente con `toFixed()` pero el problema es que me lo redondea.

Por ejemplo:

```
4.560  // necesito el 4 pero con toFixed() me devolverá 5.
```

Answer (score 5):

```html
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        
        <button onclick="myfuncion()">Presiona</button>
        
        <p id="Ejemplo"></p>    
        <script>
        function myfuncion(){
            document.getElementById("Ejemplo").innerHTML = Math.floor(4.560);
        }
        </script>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Necesitas utilizar la función Math.Floor:

Verifica este ejemplo y te dara el resultado.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el `Math.floor`, el te devuelve el primer número.

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, coloca el ejemplo para que enriquezca tu pregunta.